# How can i choose unique users in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a database with events that have happened in a game. I am trying to retrieve information about how many unique players have started a level. I use this piece of code for that:

```
heh = list(db.events.aggregate(
[
    { "$match": {"status": 'start'}},
    {"$group": {"_id": "$eventName", "players": {"$sum": 1}}},
]))
print(heh)
```

But I am getting information about how many times the level was started. How can I change my code to get the right info? Unique users have unique "uid".

Comment: You need to provide more info about the actual data and what it means for us to better help you. Also, please format your code in a nicer way.

Comment: well "status" is a directory in mongo file. Only events about levels include it. Level number is stored in "eventName" directory and as i sad every user has his own "uid". So every event has "eventName" and "uid", but only ones who i need has "status". Is this info enough? As a result i should get some thing like : [{Level 1 : 1111}, ... ].

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. $addToSet adds the unique records and then count the records in array

```
db.events.aggregate(
[
   { "$match": {"status": 'start'}},
   {"$group": {"_id": "$eventName", "players": {"$addToSet": "$uid"}}},
   {"$project": {"_id": 1, "Count": {"$size": "$players"}}}
])
```

[image: Screen]

```
db.test1.aggregate( 
[     
    { "$match": {"status": 'start'}},     
    {"$group": {"_id": "$eventName", "players": {"$addToSet": "$uid"}}},
    {$unwind:"$players"},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",count:{$sum:1}}}
]
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that "$size" work that way? I'm getting an error: "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: exception: invalid operator '$size'
". As i understood from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/ it work different way. Or i just don't understend what is wrong

Comment: Refer here: :https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Comment: Can you post few sample records? so that i can completely understand the structure of your collection.

Comment: Okey, I got it about "$size" in general, but i still have no idea why i'm getting an error

Comment: "_id" : ObjectId("570d0107712bf65fd8000000"),
    "uid" : "cf2ee9b6-21d0-4266-b3b7-73935b27c18f",
    "timestamp" : "Tue Apr 12 20:14:57 2016",
    "is_buyer" : 0,
    "gameVersion" : "1.9.1",
    "use_extra" : 0,
    "eventName" : "Level 1",
    "os" : "Android",
    "bubbles_left" : "start",
    "osVersion" : "4.3",
    "days_in_game" : 1,
    "use_special" : 0,
    "debug" : true,
    "time" : 0,
    "status" : "start",
    "bfly" : 0,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-04-12T14:07:03.113Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-04-12T14:07:03.113Z") (cant make it look like code)

Comment: I am getting proper response for that query.

Comment: I have inserted this sample record and I am getting response for this query. Whats your Mongo DB version?

Comment: Nope. In 2.6. Check here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Comment: i run 3.3 version, so that must be fine

Comment: @SivaKumar I was wrong. I run 2.4.14 mongo. Is there any possibility to replace $size with some thing else?

Comment: How about the second query? I don't have 2.4 my machine. But I just tried to avoid $size.